# Running GNOME 3 components without GNOME

Tags: gnome3, screensaver, gnome-panel

I would like to use some of the GNOME 3 components (such as the panel and screensaver) without actually using gnome shell. (To be more specific, I switched to xmonad now.)

Is there a way to do that? Back in the old days, there used to be individual executables such as `gnome-panel`, that one could run independently. But I don't see those anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You still can. But not to the same capacity as you used to. So many things, like GNOME Panel as you mentioned, have been wrapped up in GNOME shell; without the ability to remove them. The clearly standalone applications can still be used as such. Scrolling through the list on my Debian machine I saw many of them:

Calculator, games, GNOME Commander, Terminal, Maps, GTK mplayer, "Multi-Writer", music, accessibility (Orca), Paint, Power Manager (not sure if this one is standalone), PPP, RDP, Screensaver, GDM, Gsudo, Weather, GTK Network Manager front-end, gtk gVim.

That only scratches the surface. Browse around your distro's repositories or for source code to compile yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, I need specifically those two components, not just *any* gnome programs.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood you. Gnome panel has been too integrated. Why it's even listed as a separate dependency for the shell is beyond me. You'll have to find an permanent alternative, unless the whole xmonad set up is satisfactory. Help with that might warrant a separate question. On the bright side I'm pretty sure the GNOME's screensaver will still work.

Comment: How do I run gnome screensaver?

Comment: It would help if I knew what distro you were running. Obviously you'll need it installed. It should be as simple as running `gnome-screensaver` at startup, however you'd like to ensure that happens which will vary depending on DE and WM. I don't know about Xmonad, but there's probably some sort of autostart file. To edit preferences and such, `gnome-screensaver-preferences` should work. If for some reason it doesn't, there's probably some package somewhere that needs to be installed that I don't know about. `gnome-settings-daemon` might be helpful, and make sure you have dbus installed.

Comment: I'm on Fedora. The thing is, I don't have gnome-screensaver anywhere in my path, although it must be installed, since it works under gnome on the same system.

Comment: Ok, I installed the gnome-screensaver package, but that's not the same screensaver that ran under GNOME 3. It looks like a GNOME 2 screensaver.

Comment: I'm surprised for how long this took to find out, but: Fedora has the latest non-beta version of GNOME screensaver. It's absolutely the `GNOME 3` one. It should just be a theming issue if it looks like `GNOME 2`. It might actually be defaulting to the `GNOME Fallback` look when it's outside of the full session. How to fix that is outside of my expertise, and I don't want to give you bad advice.